# Java testing a method with JUnit (void)

Tags: java, junit

I have the following void method and i have no idea how to test it with a JUnit test.

```
public void removeFriend(String rf)
{
    boolean found = false;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < friendList.size() && !found)
    {
        if(friendList.get(i).equals(rf))
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }

    friendList.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: What's it removing a friend from? What's the rest of the class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presumably friendList is a field on the class where the method was defined.

So to test:

1. Create an instance of the class, and populate friendList
2. Call removeFriend with a String that should match.
3. assert that the friendList no longer contains the friend.

You probably also want to test by passing in a String for a friend that isn't in the list, to assert that the list is unchanged.

Edit: its an interesting question you raised in the comments.  I usually am very explicit with these sorts of things, so I would do

```
List<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
friendList.add("friend1");
friendList.add("friend2");

// assert before actually calling the method under test to make sure my setup is ok
assertEquals(2, friendList.size());

// theObj is an instance of the class you are testing
theObj.friendList = friendList; 

// call the method under test
theObj.removeFriend("friend1");

// be explicit, the list should now have size1 and NOT contain the removed friend
assertEquals(1, friendList.size());
assertFalse(friendList.contains("friend1");
```

Note that I have left some stuff out, but that is a general outline.  Don't forget you can test the case where you remove a String that is NOT in the list.  You might also want to test the case where the same friend is in the list two times.

Comment: Thanks is this required to do i with assertEquals? not really sure how to populate the assert.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, are you aware that you can replace the entire method with `friendList.remove(rf);`? It will do *exactly* what the method name claims (and is guaranteed to be already thoroughly tested).

As for testing, even the most dogmatic proponents of "pure" unit tests don't claim that each method of a class in an OO language has to be testable in complete isolation. Otherwise, you couldn't test OO code at all and Unit testing would be restricted to functional languages.

So what you do in the test is create an object of the class that contains the method, use its constructor or setters to put it into a specific state the method can operate on, then call the method and then test that the object is in the expected state afterwards. More concretely:

- Create an object of the class
- put some entries into `friendList`
- call `removeFriend()` with one of the entries
- test that this entry is not anymore present

Answer (score 1):

I would assume your class has more than one method.  You need to use these other methods to test the behaviour before and after calling this method.

BTW: Your method

- appears to remove the first entry if no match is found. Is this intended?
- would blow up if there were no entries.
- would blow up if any entries in friendList is null
- otherwise does the same thing as friendList.remove(rf);

I would write a test for all these conditions.

The important thing to look for is all the conditions where your method might break rather than just a situation where it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Add some friends to whatever this object is, assert that they're there. Call removeFriend(), assert that the one you removed isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You might find studying the "programming by contract" style of class design helpful. It works well with the "test driven development" (TDD) style. Briefly, you describe and document what a mutator method is meant to do only in terms of values returned by its accessible (public and protected) getter methods.